# Comparing time series data between subjects

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, medicine

We are measuring the blood concentration of a drug (1) when subjects had a meal and (2) on an empty stomach. For this, we are drawing blood at 15 minute intervals. This gives us two time series of data for each subject.

We want to show that the drug is absorbed slower when patients have eaten. Is there a statistical test to compare time series data between subjects that we could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comparing two time series, then it is advisable to detrend your time series first. This will give you an indication why:

http://svds.com/avoiding-common-mistakes-with-time-series/

Essentially, the problem with comparing two time series is that you may well find that even if the drug is absorbed slower when patients have eaten, that you will still find a degree of correlation in drug absorption between the two groups, which will not give you meaningful results.

Instead, it is better to examine the cointegration of the two time series (i.e. the extent to which the two time series converge). To do this, firstly use the Dickey-Fuller test to examine if your data is stationary, i.e. has a constant mean, variance and autocorrelation.

Then, first difference your data by subtracting each data point from the one before it:

**y'(t) = y(t) – y(t-1)**

If cointegration is present, you will find that a non-stationary time series becomes stationary upon first differencing the data. This indicates that both variables move together.